# Python for loop repeats output when appending to empty list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python to create a list from text extracted from zoom, this is the text...

```
text= """
09:04:57 РћС‚  John Aiton  РєРѕРјСѓ  Р’СЃРµ : Tomorrow I'm going on a trip GRA
09:05:05 РћС‚  John Aiton  РєРѕРјСѓ  Р’СЃРµ : now I am on a trip GRA
09:08:03 РћС‚  John Aiton  РєРѕРјСѓ  Р’СЃРµ : soon we go down south GRA
"""
```

When I tried to append to an empty list with this code

```
my = []
for line in text.splitlines():
    my.append(line[46:])
    print(my)
```

I got repeated results in the output, the beginning of which is below:

```
["Tomorrow I'm going on a trip GRA"]
["Tomorrow I'm going on a trip GRA", 'now I am on a trip GRA']
["Tomorrow I'm going on a trip GRA", 'now I am on a trip GRA', 'soon we go down south GRA']
["Tomorrow I'm going on a trip GRA", 'now I am on a trip GRA', 'soon we go down south GRA', 'meet up with a friend LRG']
["Tomorrow I'm going on a trip GRA", 'now I am on a trip GRA', 'soon we go down south GRA', 'meet up with a friend LRG', "it reminds me of a book I'm listening to now LRG"]
```

How can I avoid this repetition and end up with an output (in list or string form) like this:

```
Tomorrow I'm going on a trip GRA
now I am on a trip GRA
soon we go down south GRA
```

Comment: you are doing everything right, just print list at the end not inside `for` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `*` unpacking with `sep='\n'` argument for `print`:

```
my = []
for line in text.splitlines():
    my.append(line[46:])
print(*my, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
Tomorrow I'm going on a trip GRA
now I am on a trip GRA
soon we go down south GRA
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution wihtout using the specific index (which can cause some issue) is:

```
[l.split(' : ')[-1] for l in text.splitlines() if l]
```

So `splitlines()` will separate by `\n` and then for each entry to the list if it's not empty we will split by `:` and take the last element.

This will result in:

```
["Tomorrow I'm going on a trip GRA",
 'now I am on a trip GRA',
 'soon we go down south GRA']
```

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 main ways:

- print each row **during** iterating

  ```
  my = []
  for line in text.splitlines():
      my.append(line[46:])
      print(my[-1])
  ```
- print each **after** iterating

  ```
  for x in my:
      print(x)

  // or 
  print(*my, sep='\n')
  ```